# Write variable in variable without recognizing it

Tags: php

Just a quick question. I'm having trouble with writing variable ($var) just as text, example:

```
$header = "

<?php
$title ='title';
$work = 'work';
$about = 'about';
$contact = 'contact';
?>

";
```

and now I should be ablw to echo it as it is. But I get errors that those variables are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in double quoted strings in PHP are interpolated. Escape the dollar signs.

```
$header = "

<?php
\$title ='title';
\$work = 'work';
\$about = 'about';
\$contact = 'contact';
?>

";
```

Comment: Thanks for really fast answer, best regards.